# The convergence of a sequence

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

This problem is form the Romanian GM.

Let $(x_{n})_{n\geq1}$ be a sequence of real numbers defined by $x_{1}=1$ and $$x_{n+1}=x_{n}+ \frac{\sqrt{n}}{x_{n}}$$ for all $n \geq 1$. Study the convergence of the sequence $$(\frac{x_{n}}{n^{\frac{3}{4}}})_{n\geq1}$$

I only managed to show from the given relation that $(x_{n})_{n\geq1}$ is strictly increasing and tends to $+\infty$.

Comment: The limit is equal to $\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$, so we could try to prove $x_n=\Theta( \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}n^{\frac{3}{4}}   )$ inductively

Comment: How did you find that limit?

Comment: By solving the ODE $y'= \sqrt{x}/y$, the continuous analogue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, $$x_{n+1}=x_{n}+ \frac{\sqrt{n}}{x_{n}}$$ implies
$$x^2_{n+1}=x^2_{n}+ 2\sqrt{n}+\frac{n}{x^2_{n}},$$ so $$x^2_n=2\sum^{n-1}_{k=1}\sqrt{k}+O(\sqrt{n})=\frac43\,n^{3/2}+O(\sqrt{n}),$$
meaning the limit is $\displaystyle\frac2{\sqrt{3}}$, as @clark announced.
If that was a bit rushed: we get $$x^2_{n+1}\ge x^2_{n}+ 2\sqrt{n},$$ first, so
$$x^2_n\ge2\sum^{n-1}_{k=1}\sqrt{k}=\frac43\,n^{3/2}+O(\sqrt{n}),$$ and consequently $$\sum^{n-1}_{k=1}\frac{k}{x^2_{k}}=O(\sqrt{n}).$$ And $$x^2_n=\frac43\,n^{3/2}+O(\sqrt{n})=\frac43\,n^{3/2}\left(1+O\left(\frac1n\right)\right)$$ happens to be equivalent with $$x_n=\sqrt{\frac43}\,n^{3/4}\left(1+O\left(\frac1n\right)\right),$$ so
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_n}{n^{3/4}}=\sqrt{\frac43}=\frac2{\sqrt{3}}.$$
I'm sorry answers at MSE were never meant to explain entire concepts, but if you are unsure concerning the notation, check [Big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), please.

Comment: How did you get rid of the $\frac{n}{x^2_{n}}$ terms?

Comment: @Martin R I didn't get rid of it, that's absorbed in the $O(\sqrt{n})$ thingy. You're right, I should make that a bit more explicit.

Comment: @ProfessorVector  I am not sure I understand that "thingy", it looks like it has the limit $+\infty$ too

Comment: Still don't understand how you obtain the limit :)

Comment: @razvanelda That's true, but it's a smaller $\infty$ than the $n^{3/2}$ term.

Comment: @ProfessorVector Why? I agree it is smaller, but why it's limit is $0$ after you extract $\frac{4}{3}n^{3/2}$?

Answer (score 0):

$$x_{n+1}=x_{n}+ \frac{\sqrt{n}}{x_{n}}\implies
x^2_{n+1}-x^2_{n}=2\sqrt{n}+\frac{n}{x^2_{n}}.$$
Using Stolz's theorem twice: first, consider limit
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x^2_n}{n}
=\lim_{n\to\infty}(x^2_{n+1}-x^2_n)
=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(2\sqrt{n}+\frac{n}{x_n^2}\right)=\infty,$$
which implies
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{x^2_n}=0.$$
Second,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x^2_n}{\sqrt{n^3}}
=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x^2_{n+1}-x^2_n}{\sqrt{(n+1)^3}-\sqrt{n^3}}
=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2\sqrt{n}+\frac{n}{x_n^2}}{\sqrt{(n+1)^3}-\sqrt{n^3}}\\
=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{(n+1)^3}+\sqrt{n^3}}{(n+1)^3-n^3}\cdot\left(2\sqrt{n}+\frac{n}{x_n^2}\right)\\
=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2\sqrt{n^3}}{3n^2}\cdot\left(2\sqrt{n}+\frac{n}{x_n^2}\right)=\frac{4}{3}.$$
So
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_n}{n^{3/4}}=\frac2{\sqrt{3}}.$$